# Jqgrid is not resizing as the resolution changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

[image][image][![distorted header and footer after resizing]
I am using jqgrid 3.8.2. When I am changing the resolution of the window, I notice that the jqgrid's width and position remains the same instead of getting fit into the given resolution. I tried using `resize` and `setGridwidth`, but with no luck.I need support in chrome,IE9 and firefox.I also b=noticed that the width of grid table is fixed to some value.,How can I resize it upon changing resolutions without affecting the hdiv,bdiv and sdiv components?

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    //alert("resize")
    jQuery("#list").setGridWidth($(window).width());
    $('#gbox_list').width('');
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Which web browsers you need support (which version of IE: ie8 for example or only higher)? What `resize` you used and it don't worked?

Comment: Hi I need support in chrome,mozilla and IE9.Attaching the code of the resize function

Comment: Edit the information into your question instead of a comment, and provide as much information as you can. This way you're more likely to get answers

Comment: You add the text "without affecting the hdiv, bdiv and sdiv components". Sorry, but it has no sense. The grid consist from relatively complex structure of divs and tables. The width of bdiv (body div), hdiv (header div) and sdiv (summary, footer div) **must** corresponds to the width of the main `<table>` with the main data.

Comment: @Oleg  Thanks for the response.But I see the header and footer not aligned with the grid cells.Is it because of the fixed column width given in the colmodel? How can I make the header and footer row change dynamically with the grid resize?

Comment: @PoornaMurali: You have to provide the demo,which reproduces the problem. No my tests have any problems.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Is it fine if I attach the screenshot showing the problems.I tried reproducing in fiddle.But somehow, the grid is not rendering at all.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function(){
    table.jqGrid('setGridWidth', container.width());
})
```

table is the table element in the jqGrid, and containeris the div containing the jqGrid element

Comment: @PoornaMurali: Sorry, but it should do working! You should verify what you do (`table` and `container`). The exact results of resizing could a little depend on other options, which you use in jqGrid (`shrinkToFit` option for example).

Comment: Hi Oleg, Now I am able to resize the grid, but the footer and the header row are not aligned with the grid.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118099/jqgrid-resizing-footer-row-and-header-row-is-distortes-and-not-aligned-with-the  attaching the screen shot as well.

Comment: @PoornaMurali: You should provide the demo which reproduce the problem. It could be that you have some problem because you use retro version of jqGrid. More modern version of of jqGrid have no such problems. See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/8/ which uses `classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"` additionally for hiding the last column based on the resolution of the grid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.Can I also use these classes in my grid.Or is it supportive only in the latest versions of the grid?

Comment: @PoornaMurali: jqGrid 3.8.2 is **very old**. It's almost 5 years old, it developed at the time of Internet Explorer 8 which is out now. `labelClasses` are not supported of cause in the versions. I implemented the feature in my fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)) starting with version 4.8. The current version of free jqGrid 4.9.2, but I plan to publish 4.9.3 very soon.