# JQGrid resizing-footer row and header row is distortes and not aligned with the jqgrid after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jqgrid

I tried resizing of jqgrid with the following code,

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
                    jQuery("#list").setGridWidth($('#jQGrid').width(), true);
                }).trigger('resize');
```

The grid gets resized, but the footer row that has the userdata and the header row that holds the column names are distorted and not aligned with the grid column cells.Is it possible to resize the footer and header automatically with the jqgrid? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Poorna.

Comment: just try to trigger refresh th grid with data refresh false might help. It did once for me.

Comment: i tried refreshing with this 
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'xml'}).trigger('reloadGrid')
 but with no luck..:(

Comment: Thanks for the response flipper.I tried reloading,but with no luck. :(